# Route Map in iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-maps, routes, directions

Does iPhone sdk supports route between two places on Map? I have searched many times. But not able to find any reference. Even on apple iphone development forums, there is no such thing available.

I have done this functionality using google map url. In which I have to pass source and destination latitude & longitude. I am getting the map but it is not as much good as like the iphone google map.

Can anyone help me out to do this functionality? I need to display map route between two places and also want description of the exact path to reach the destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the API has no means to do routing.  You can do overlays if you can figure out the route, but that's obviously a lot more work.